# Less Mixins with dynamic variable, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, less, mixins

I have a less mixin that ellipsis a string.

```
.ellipse-text(@params){
  max-width: @params;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

This works wonderful... if I know the exact max-width, which I don't. I have a tree structure that looks like the following...

```
name
----> name
      ----> name
name
----> name
      ----> name
            ---> name
```

I need to calculate the width of the name attribute (it will get smaller as it get farther right) and then pass that number as a variable.

I am also using AngularJS and thought I maybe could do something like this?  But at the same time I'm not event sure I can apply a mixin directly to an attribute.

```
<div class=" ellipse-text( {{myWidth}} )" >name</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: no you cant pass less mixins in class attributes,but you can control css through javascript with or without angularjs.

Comment: I'm wondering if even this `<div class=" ellipse-text(100px)" >name</div>` works at all...